# how to delete item comments with PnP?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, comments, list-comments

How can I make the delete() function of the IComments interface work?

The promise of then() returns an ICommentInfo interface and delete() doesn't work.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IComments` interface instead of `ICommentInfo`. Try using code like below:

```
import { spfi } from "@pnp/sp";
import { IComments } from "@pnp/sp/comments";

const sp = spfi(...);

const item = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Prova").items.getById(1);
const comments: IComments = await item.comments();

// these will be Comment instances in the array
comments[0].delete()
```

**Reference**: [PnP JS - Delete a Comment](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/comments-likes/#delete-a-comment)

---

**Update**:

To delete all comments on a list item, you can use the clear method exposed by `IComments` interface:

```
const item = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Prova").items.getById(1);
await item.comments.clear();
```

Or you can delete a specific comment by ID as given below:

```
const commentId = 1;
await item.comments.getById(commentId).delete();
```

Comment: Above example deletes the first commend found via API call. If you want to delete all comments, you can loop on `comments` array and delete it one by one. Let me know if you need any help with it.

Comment: I tried what you told me, also following the PnP documentation, but I get the same error (TypeError: comments [0] .delete() is not a function)

Comment: Did you type casted results to `IComments`? Which version of PnP JS are you using?

Comment: You can also delete the list comments using SharePoint REST API as explained at: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/14/delete-comments-from-list-item-using-sharepoint-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it by modifying the code like this: await item.comments.getById(id) .delete ()